# Crossmint error: Configuration error Wrong price, expected 0.029 received 0.001

Tags: crossmint

i have an issue on my website. Implemented crossmint on my site and trying to test it with cc and get the following error code: Configuration error

Wrong price, expected 0.029 received 0.001

Please let me know how i can fix it.

I expected the cc payment work, but it didn't.

Comment: Mind sharing:
1. The code you are using to instantiate the CrossmintPayButton (i.e. what are you passing to the SDK)
2. Which blockchain and smart contract you're using

Answer (score 0):

This likely happened because the price in your smart contract doesn't match the price in your button code. Updating the mintConfig to the following value for totalPrice will fix it.

```
mintConfig='{
    "totalPrice": "0.029",
    "quantity": "1",
    "customParam": "customValue"
}'
```

If you have a quantity parameter or any other values in your existing mintConfig you'll need to keep those also.